# Button's unexpected behavior while oncilck event fired in html/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the below code I am rotating the button to 90 deg and fixing the position.
I need this button to be fixed on that position even after on-click.
How ever after  clicking the button the position changed to actual position (0 deg).

The button's scale-up and scale-down effects also not working while clicking.

I have attached an image for better understanding of the problem behavior.

```
#action_btn
{
position:absolute;
width:81px;
height:20px;
background-image:url(image/action_btn.png);
margin-top:82px;
margin-left:30px;
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(90deg);

}

#action_btn input
{
    width:81px;
    height:20px;
    opacity:0.0;

}

#action_btn :active{

-webkit-transform: scale(0.95,0.95);
-moz-transform:scale(0.95,0.95);    

}
```

[image]

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Transforms aren't additive like that: the `:active` state value is going to replace the non-active value, and so you'll *only* get the scale. You'll need to include both the rotations and the scale in your `:active` rule.

Comment: if I write rotations code inside active rule the button will be on vertical position after clicking the button. But I need the button in vertical position when view loads.

Comment: I'm not saying to *remove* the non-active rule. I'm saying that you need to add the rotation to the active rule. That way regardless of state, the button will be rotated.

Comment: Could you able to create any fiddle for this ?? that would help to solve this

Comment: If I change my code as per your suggestion scale-up and scale-down effects is not working.

Comment: If I understand correctly what you've described, I think it seems working to me http://jsfiddle.net/4Jp4f/

Comment: you understand correctly, the code is working fine in jsfiddle where as not working on my demo project. What might be the problem any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

[Do you mean something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/2De2N/)

I simply made a class called `active` and let that add to that div when its clicked by using jQuery. Heres the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#action_btn').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

And for the CSS:

```
#action_btn.active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95, 0.95);
    -moz-transform:scale(0.95, 0.95);
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want it to toggle the class, use [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2De2N/1/).

It simply activates and deactivates the class when you click on the red box.

Comment: @DKBHOI What do you mean then? Do you want to do it without jQuery? Wich makes it a little harder tho :P